# py2exe using 'requests'

Tags: python, python-3.4

**Code** (simple version)

```
import requests

url = 'https://...'
payload = {'key1': 'value1'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Works wonderfully.

**Problem**.

Wouldn't work with py2exe though, I was getting:

```
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

A **band-aid** was to include the following on **setup.py**:

```
import requests.certs

build_exe_options = {"include_files":[(requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')]}
```

A new problem arises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "posturl.py", line 5, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
from .packages import chardet
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import urllib3
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
from .packages.six.moves.queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
mod = mod._resolve()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'
```

I tried adding import queue on setup.py but no cigar.

What can I do here to compile a standalone exe of my script?

Comment: Switched to pyinstaller, added 'import queue' on the script & did a 'pyinstaller -F myscript.py' works flawlessly. If you're having trouble generating an exe, I recommend pyinstaller. Thank you all.

Comment: if this fixes your problem, please add it as a proper "Answer" and `accept` it (so the Q doesn't show up as "unanswered")